# should I load all data from json file into html or load everytime from json file

Tags: javascript, html, json

i need to load different data values from json file.. 
should I load all data from json file into html  or i load everytime from json file? . for example i'm loading values on a menu change

currently i'm appending all listmenu items in UL and adding values into attributes. so on selecting any menu item, all the attributes are called..

..

```
for(i = 0; i < list.items.length; i++) {
        $('#listMenu ul').append('<li value="' + list.items[i].itemId + '" discoun="'+list.items[i].discout+'" link="'+list.items[i].link+'">'+list.items[i].name + "</li>")

       }
```

Now i want to know.. what is the better way of getting from json file.. am i using the right way or not? because i'm worried if there is discription of too many lines.. that will become an issue for performance!

Comment: i think.. i must declare some global variables and pass root of json objects.. and call them from json file if data is larger .. and if only yes/no's or small values. then load them into html .. right?

Answer (score 1):

If your data which you get from json is permanently,it much better to load into html.

Comment: i think.. i must declare some global variables and pass root of json objects.. and call them from json file if data is larger .. and if only yes/no's or small values. then load them into html .. right?